# Reading from file in C using fread

Tags: c

I'm learning how to read content from a file in C. And I manage to scrape through the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void read_content(FILE *file) {
  char *x = malloc(20);
  // read first 20 char
  int read = fread(x,sizeof(char),20,file);
  if (read != 20) {
     printf("Read could not happen\n");
   }
  else {
      printf("the content read is %s",x);
  }
  free(x);
  return; 
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fp; 
  fp = fopen("test.txt","w+");
  read_content(fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

But for some reason (which I'm not able to understand) I see the `read` bytes count as `0`.

Comment: That's what you get for not checking the return value of `fopen()`

Comment: `if (!fp) { perror("test.txt : "); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: And fyi, you're creating your file from scratch whether it exists or not. [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) with `"w+"` destroys the current file and creates a new empty one if permissible. So even if the open succeeds, there's no "there" there.

Comment: This will not fix your erors:
fresult can return less than 20 characters! And presuming the input always ends with a terminating zero is very bad programming habbit.

Comment: Dear OP, it is probably the file who is not being created as in the path given there's no file exist and then you read nothing as its an empty file.

Comment: `fp = fopen("test.txt","w+");` A tough question: out of the possible set of (read, write), which word you think corresponds to the letter "w" in the parameter of `fopen`? A tougher question: what does `+` stand for?

Comment: @WhozCraig true. I agree.

Comment: @WhozCraig if (fp != NULL) , don't use (!fp)

Comment: another problem with the code is you're allocating 20 bytes and then reading 20 bytes in to that space. strings in C need extra space to store the terminating `'\0'` character at the end so either you need to allocate 21 or only read in 19. And then also add that terminating character too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you open the file with the `w+` mode. There are two possibilities:

- if the file doesn't exist, it will be created empty. Reading from it immediately gives end of file resulting in `fread()` returning 0.
- if the file *does* exist, it will be truncated i.e. changed into an empty file. Reading from it immediately gives end of file resulting in `fread()` returning 0.

If you just want to read from the file (as per your example), open it in mode `r`. If you want to read and write without destroying its existing content, use mode `r+`.

Whatever mode you choose, always check that `fopen()` returns non null and print the error if it returns null (this is not the cause of your problem but is best practice).

Answer (score 1):

From [Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) `w+` flag:

> Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
>                 not exist, otherwise it is truncated.

You are probably trying to open a file which doesn't exist at the path you provided, or is `read-only` as @WhozCraig suggested in comment. This means a new file is being created, an empty file! hence you are seeing `0` bytes read.

To sum up, The `fopen` is failing, in that case you need to check the return value if it is equal to `-1`. 
To find what was the error, you can check the `errno` as it is set to
indicate the error.

If you are only intending to read, open the file with `r` flag instead of `w+`

Comment: It doesn't matter if the file exists or not: "otherwise it is truncated" tells you that a file that already exists has its content deleted so that it is now an empty file.

Comment: Also, the problem is nothing to do with failing to open the file or not. It's the mode that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within this line of code:

```
fp = fopen("test.txt","w+")
```

the `"w+"` mode, clear the previous content of the file and the file will be empty when you just going to read the file without writing anything to it. Hence, it is printing `"Read could not happen"` because you are trying to read an empty file.

I would suggest you to use `"r+"` mode, if you are willing to read and then write into the file. Otherwise, `r` mode is good enough for simple reading of a file.